# How to use mobaxterm with 2 factor authentication (Authenticator app)

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm, two-factor-authentication, windows-authentication

I would like to use mobaxterm with 2 factor authentication (needed for the jump server). I.e. the jump server asks for approval from the Microsoft authenticator ( after logging in with the normal password).
I had this set up with jump server and target, in the old days, when no 2factor was used.
I updated by enabling the 2 factor authentication from Settings->SSH.
Subsequently, created a new session with the jump server and the target. However, when clicking on the session I get the message "`SSH connection to gateway server failed with message [Error connection to gateway server]`".
That is rather strange, since I made a separate session connecting to the gateway server only and it works fine with the MS authentication from my phone.
I guess that the jump part is somehow missconfigured.
I will appreciate your help.

**EDIT**

I just checked, and the following works:

`ssh -XYt username@jump.server.com ssh -XYt username@pcfinal`
It is also possible to do the same via: `Advanced SSH-> execute command`, where the command is `ssh -XYt username@pcfinal`.
The question is how to do it via the gui, so that I don't have two type passwords every time? In the past I was able to connect just by clicking the session. All password were automatically managed by mobaxterm.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the actual authentication that's going on. See if mobaxterm can be made to log debugging information about the ssh connection. Or try running the "ssh" command-line utility with the "-vv" option to print debugging output. Once you've done that, [edit] your question to include the debugging output.

Comment: Have you reached out to the author of Mobaxterm for this?  They are indeed kind and responsive (esp if you actually pay for a license).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I will try to do it.

Comment: Please also choose a single question to ask here, and edit your post to remove other questions. This site requires single questions that can get single answers.